# How can I interpret user input as a function in Julia?

Tags: julia

I've been using the following function to take in user input for something I'm writing in Julia:

```
function input(prompt::AbstractString = "")
    println(prompt * " ")
    chomp(readline())
end
```

In my particular case, the input that I'm taking in is in the form of equations such as "y = x^2". After the input() function passes it to me as an ASCIIString, I then use the parse() function to convert it to an Expression:

```
:(y = x^2)
```

As an Expression, I can use the .args attribute to do things like counting the number of variables and returning the unique variables, all of which has worked fine. Now, I need to be able to evaluate the right side of the expression as the Function f(x) = x^2. To do so, I began writing the following function (which has some pretty major flaws):

```
function evalExpression()
    L = [1,2,3,4]
    equation = parse(input("Enter an equation")) 
    f = equation.args[2].args[2] 
    for i in L
        x = i
        value = eval(f)
        println(value)
    end
end
```

This function has two problems that I haven't been able to resolve. The first is that it gives me an UndefVarError for x when I try to run it right now; that's more or less expected. The second is that unless I knew that the user would input a function of only x, I would have no way of figuring out what the variables I needed to assign were. I wrote a recursive function that can take in an expression and return all its variables in the form of [:x, :y, etc.], but I cannot assign :x to a number to evaluate the function--I need to assign it just to x, and I cannot figure out how to access that. Is there anything that I can use to access the variables I need? Or a different approach I could take?

Thank you!

Comment: One suggestion: organize code to build up an entire expression and then evaluate it at once, vs. eval'ing pieces individually. Reasoning about each step might be easier. E.g., for the given problem, the idea is to start from what you want and build a similar corresponding expression by hand. You want `f(x) = x^2`, so look at `parse("f(x) = x^2") |> dump` (`dump` is very useful for debugging expressions!). Since you have code to get the variable names, you can fill in a similar expression: `myexpr = Expr(:(=), Expr(:call, :f, :x, :y, :z), Expr([equation expr here])`, then `eval(myexpr)` it.

Comment: A possibly-helpful model is FastAnonymous.jl. With julia-0.5, this package will no longer needed for performance, but it perform manipulations of the types you need to do here. You could even use it directly: just ask the user to write the "equation" as `x -> x^2`, prepend the string with an `@anon`, and then `eval(parse(str))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run the following:

```
function evalExpression()
    L = [1,2,3,4]
    equation = parse(input("Enter an equation"))
    global x
    for i in L
        x = i
        f = equation.args[2].args[2] 
        value = eval(f)
        println(value)
    end
end
```

and then putting y = x*x I get

```
evalExpression()
    Enter an equation 
    y = x*x
    1
    2
    3
    4
```

What is missing, at least for x as a variable, is declaring it globally. When you eval parsed statements, these parsed statements only access global variables

So what you probably need to do after you've invented your recursive function to correctly fetch variables, is to create them globally. Maybe

```
eval(parse("$variable = 0"))
```

will do